# How to split my site in the Yii2 logic

Tags: php, yii, yii2, gii

Let's say, I have a mobile application, which goal is to facilitate the work of operators who work in the field with clients and their "top-brass" to track their KPI. It's already written on Yii 1.1 and now the task is to migrate this application on 2.0. But I need some advices about architecture.

I have login page, I have page with different stuff like bills, clients, reports with information about clients (for operator) or list of operators for managers who lead them, and which of the menu item falls into the client profile or list of clients or operators (depends on).

What should I use to split information logically in my app? For example, widgets? In the previous version of my application I used blocks logic:

```
public function renderBlock( $name, $view = null )
{
    $res = '';
    if ( isset( $this->_blocks[ $name ] ) && $this->_blocks[ $name ] instanceof Block )
    {
        if ($view)
        {
            $this->_blocks[ $name ]->setView($view);
        }
        $res = $this->_blocks[ $name ]->run();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error render $name block.";
    }
    return $res;
}
```

and:

```
abstract class Block extends CWidget
```

But now I realised that it was a bit of tangled logic and needs to refactor. What's your recommendations?

Comment: you can check in layout/main.php login from mobile or desktop. Based on the value you can decide your files to load for mobile or desktop.
and redirect the user to your the mobike version of site or desktop.
Ask for any help